# NodeJS reading dynamically directory

Tags: javascript, node.js, readfile, readdir

I am making a tool that reads text files from a directory. I am using NodeJS fs.readdir and fs.readFile functions. The problem is that if I add a new folder I have to run the server again. Do you have any suggestions how to make it dynamic without restarting the server?

Comment: Hm, I just made a quick web server and it seemed to reflect changes on dir without restarting [server](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/7e4e70c232cf7aef8ea9)

Answer (score 1):

I use nodemon when I'm developing. It monitors my asset files and runs a script to compile it when a file changes.

You could also use it to monitor for new files. And run your script when a new file is put into the directory.

[Nodemon](https://github.com/remy/nodemon)

Answer (score 0):

Yes i think nodmon what you want

nodemon will watch the files in the directory in which nodemon was started, and if any files change, nodemon will automatically restart your node application.

nodemon does not require any changes to your code or method of development. nodemon simply wraps your node application and keeps an eye on any files that have changed. Remember that nodemon is a replacement wrapper for node, think of it as replacing the word "node" on the command line when you run your script.

Answer (score 0):

```
https://github.com/paulmillr/chokidar
```

This node module is good for watching over directory. it emmits events for creating, updating, deleting and almost every directory/file operation.